# setColumnDefs function call server side C# code 2 times

Tags: c#, ag-grid

In our asp.net(webform, c#) project, we use AG-Grid control, we bought the license, now in my 'Refresh' button, code is like this

```
gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs([]);
gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(columns);
```

`gridOptions` is our defines variable, here `setColumnDefs` will call `ColumnController.prototype.setColumnDefs` in ag-grid-enterprise.js(version is v20.1.0),
but I found this 2 line code invoke server side method 2 times(this method is to get grid data in my TempListHandler.ashx file)

If remove the code `gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs([]);`, it has issues, but if write code like this, it invoke method 2 times,

Does anyone have some suggestion?

Comment: Why do you need `gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs([]);`?

Comment: because if remove gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs([]);, there is some issue when get data

Comment: There's not enough information in your question for it to be answerable. You will have to provide more details.

Comment: @thirtydot, there is enough information in the question. The `setColumnDefs` causes data to be reloaded. I face the same issue and have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: @manymanymore: It only seems like there's enough information because you also have a test case of the problem. I don't have that, so to answer this I would need to go through a lot of work just to reproduce the problem. Then I could try fix it. Nobody can "just know" the answer to this without a test case (unless they've previously fixed the problem). It's probably a bug in ag-grid. To get an answer here, you'd need to fork one of the demos from ag-grid docs and reproduce the problem in there (shim in the XHR calls like they do in some of the other demos). Then someone can help.

Comment: @thirtydot, you are right. Sorry, thanks.